# Getting config.eager_load is set to nil while trying to run rails c in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config, environment

I'm trying to run the rails (`4.1.2`) console

```
rails c RAILS_ENV=test
```

And I'm getting this:

```
> config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your
> config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
> 
>   * development - set it to false   * test - set it to false (unless
> you use a tool that preloads your test environment)   * production -
> set it to true
> 
> /Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in
> `resolve_symbol_connection': 'RAILS_ENV=test' database is not
> configured. Available: ["development", "test", "production"]
> (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Yet in my `test.rb` I have `config.eager_load = false` and my `database.yml` is ok (I ran `rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test` without issues.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I got this error when I ran `RAILS_ENV=teste rails db:migrate` ... note the extra 'e' in 'teste'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to declare the env before you run the commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c
```

I get the same output on my computer:

```
> bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=test                                                                                                               ian@Ians-MacBook-Pro
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true
```

but when I run as suggested:

```
> RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c                                                                                                               ian@Ians-MacBook-Pro
Loading test environment (Rails 4.2.3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Needs to set

```
config.eager_load = false
```

for config/environments/development.rb and test.rb or `= true` for production.rb (as default)

Answer (score 2):

As for Windows systems:

1. This should do:

   ```
   rails c -e test
   ```
2. Or set the `RAILS_ENV` variable first:

   ```
   set RAILS_ENV=test
   rails c
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your

- production.rb
- development.rb
- test.rb

files in config/environments/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there is a glitch with `RAILS_ENV`. If you run

```
SET RAILS_ENV=development<SPACE>   <- with a space symbol after word "development"
```

then you will get the error:

> `config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your
>   config/environments/*.rb fil es accordingly:`

when doing `rails server webrick`.

So make sure you do type without a trailing space (and no quotes)

```
SET RAILS_ENV=development<ENTER>
```

The same applies to all environments: test, production and development.

Answer (score 0):

This is silly, but I was running into this when I was running `rails c` instead of `rails g`. Makes sense since what I was passing to the generate command is invalid for the console command.