# config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When attempting to run -- rails db migrate, I'm getting: config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

I saw a similar error post here (Getting config.eager_load is set to nil while trying to run rails c in test
)and tried running the following per that author's suggestions:

```
C:\Users\Royal and Carla\Desktop\TBPt1>SET RAILS_ENV=development
C:\Users\Royal and Carla\Desktop\TBPt1>SET RAILS_ENV=production
C:\Users\Royal and Carla\Desktop\TBPt1>SET RAILS_ENV=test
```

I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: Hopefully you have solved the problem by now. I ended up using `rake db:migrate`, instead of `rails db migrate` and it worked.

Comment: duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999625/getting-config-eager-load-is-set-to-nil-while-trying-to-run-rails-c-in-test